# Finding missing array : PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find missing in array.

with this code

```
<?php                       
     $no = array(1,2,3,5,6,7);
     $max=max($no);
     for($x=0; $x<=$max; $x++){
       if(!in_array($x,$no)){ 
       $id = $x;
       }else{
       $id = $x+1;
       }                        
     }
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($id);
?>
```

but the result is

> 8

someone can help me?

Comment: your trying to store the missing number to another variable right?

Comment: Do you want to find the first missing value or *all* the missing values? Do the missing values start at 0 or the minimum value in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your loop to the end, regardless of whether you find a missing value or not. Thus `$id` will always be `$max+1`. You need to break out of the loop when you find a missing value (or if you want all missing values, push the missing value to an array). However, the code can be more simply implemented using [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) on a [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) from 0 to the maximum value in `$no`:

```
$no = array(1,2,3,5,6,7);
$max = max($no);
// you may want to use min($no) here
$min = 0;
$missing = array_diff(range($min, $max), $no);
// print all missing values in the range
print_r($missing);
// if you only want the first missing value
echo min($missing);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [4] => 4
)
0
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mARZ3)